# Use Apache as Forward Proxy in a Proxy Chain including Proxy Authentication

Tags: apache, proxy, webserver, http-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm building a proxy chain to access an internal proxy from the outside with additional authentication:

```
Internet -> [Apache Forward Proxy] -> [Internal Squid Proxy] -> Internal Website
```

The Apache Forward Proxy is doing TLS including Certificate Based Authentication (CBA), the Squid Proxy requires basic auth with username / password. Authentication works as expected for both components.

Challenge is now to get the Apache to act as a Forward Proxy and to forward the Proxy-Authorization header from the user to the internal Proxy.

Here is the current configuration I'm using (mod_proxy and mod_proxy_connect are enabled):

```
# Enable forward proxy
ProxyRequests On

# Pass all requests on to the squid proxy
ProxyRemote * http://proxy.internal:3128

# Only allow proxy connect to port 443
AllowCONNECT 443
```

With this setup the Apache doesn't forward the Proxy-Authorization header to the internal proxy. All settings I could find for this topic (Proxy-Chain-Auth, ProxyAddHeaders, rewrite rules etc.) only work in Reverse Proxy mode using ProxyPass. But a Reverse Proxy doesn't fit here since in this mode the Apache modifies the header and the CONNECT for TLS webservers won't work.

The Apache doesn't forward any header fields from the client, in the end a request from the Apache to the internal Proxy looks like this:

```
CONNECT someserver.de:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n
Proxy-agent: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)\r\n
\r\n
```

I'm aware the Proxy-Authorization field is a Hop-by-hop field which is normally not allowed to passed to the next proxy.

Is it still possible to get the Apache to forward a Proxy-Authorization header to the internal Proxy when acting as Forward Proxy?

There is a bug for a related topic in the Apache bugtracker. But this one is to specify the username/password hard-coded in the apache config which is not what I need. I want to forward the client authorization individually.
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37355

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar setup and the env variable Proxy-Chain-Auth is the solution to your problem. You can configure the apache as follows:

```
SetEnv Proxy-Chain-Auth On
# Setting the request header is not needed in your case
# but related to the bug report mentioned in the question
RequestHeader set Proxy-Authorization "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz"
ProxyRemote * http://proxy.internal:3128
```

By setting the env variable Proxy-Chain-Auth, the authorization credentials are forwarded to the next proxy, aka proxy.internal:3128. Additionally you could set the proxy authorization header yourself - that would usually be provided by the client - with static/hard coded basic auth credentials that the squid proxy wants. This is a possible solution to the problem in the bug report:  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37355

This solution worked for me with apache 2.4.57